# Getting out of the loop in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am a noob to the extjs 4 MVC design. I have the following code.

```
onLaunch: function() {
        console.log("Launched Business Unit Controller");
        var businessunitsStore = this.getStore('Businessunits');
        businessunitsStore.load(function(records){
            var comp = Ext.getCmp('business_form');            
            for(var i=0;i<records.length;i++){
                bu = records[i].data;
                console.log(bu);
                comp.add({
                    xtype:'button',
                    cls:'x-button',
                    width:90,
                    autoScroll:false,
                    height:60,                                            
                    text:bu.businessunit_name,
                    enableToggle:true,  
                    listeners:{
                        click: function(){
                            var pnl = Ext.getCmp('active-units-form');    
                            pnl.add({
                                xtype:'label',                                
                                text:this.text,                                
                            })                         
                        } 
                    }                                         
                }) //comp.add
            } //for ...
        });       
    }
```

As you can see i am adding a button on store load, and each button has further events down the line. The problem is i want to handle the sub events like the click events of the buttons down the chain outside the onLaunch as a separate method. But it seems like i cannot get out of this loop and all events are to be written as a chain. But it seems so wrong and with increasing amount of listeners, code gets messy. So is there a way that i can switch back and forth between controller methods and internals

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: the code i have is working, i want to tidy it up thats it. For instance i want to handle the click event of the buttons i am adding to the form dynamically, outside the onLaunch method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why didn't you use the eventbus (controls)? It is already there when you use a MVC app so I recommend to use it. When using it you have the listener method within your controller and the button instance as argument. The `this` keyword will give you the controller instance while you can use the button instance to navigate up and / down using `up()` / `down()`. For sure can add another unique identifier and check it is required.

```
onLaunch: function() {
    controls('#business_form button[ident=businessunit-btn]':{click:this.onClickBussinesUnitBtn});
    console.log("Launched Business Unit Controller");
    var businessunitsStore = this.getStore('Businessunits');
    businessunitsStore.load(function(records){
        var comp = Ext.getCmp('business_form');            
        for(var i=0;i<records.length;i++){
            bu = records[i].data;
            console.log(bu);
            comp.add({
                xtype:'button',
                cls:'x-button',
                ident: 'businessunit-btn',
                width:90,
                autoScroll:false,
                height:60,                                            
                text:bu.businessunit_name,
                enableToggle:true                                       
            }) //comp.add
        } //for ...
    });       
},
onClickBussinesUnitBtn: function(btn){
     var pnl = Ext.getCmp('active-units-form'); // I recommend you to instantiate this either also with a controller function, so that you can store the reference or doing it with up/down as Alexey mentioned.
     pnl.add({
        xtype:'label',                                
        text:btn.text
     });                                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better avoid using `this` keyword if you are not sure what will it be.

```
click: function (button) {
    var pnl = Ext.getCmp('active-units-form');    
    pnl.add({
        xtype: 'label',                                
        text: button.text,                                
    })                         
}
```

Also try use `down` method instead of `Ext.getCmp` if views that you are searching for are defined in controller's `Views` config.

```
onLaunch: function() {
    console.log("Launched Business Unit Controller");
    var businessunitsStore = this.getStore('Businessunits');
    businessunitsStore.load(function(records){
        var comp = this.down('#business_form'); //Ext.getCmp('business_form');            
        for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++){
            bu = records[i]; //.data;
            console.log(bu);

            var button = comp.add({
                xtype:'button',
                cls:'x-button',
                width:90,
                autoScroll:false,
                height:60,                                            
                text:bu.get('businessunit_name'), //bu.businessunit_name,
                enableToggle:true,  
            }) //comp.add

            button.on('click', this.businessUnitButton_click, this); 
            // 3rd parameter 'this' will be controller instance inside handler
        } //for ...
    });       
},

businessUnitButton_click: function (button) {
    // 'this' is controller
    var pnl = this.down('#active-units-form'); // Ext.getCmp('active-units-form');
    pnl.add({
        xtype:'label',                                
        text: button.text,                                
    })                         
}
```